# Get Textbox Value and drop in HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is probably super simple, but here it goes...

```
<input type='textbox' name='qtybox' id='qtybox' style='width:20px;'> <a href=""/Cart.asp?Code=123456&QTY=GET QTYBOX VALUE HERE"" onclick=""somefunction(this, event); return false;"" title=""Add To Cart""><img src=""testbutton.gif"" alt=""Add To Cart"" title=""Add To Cart""/></a>
```

I've tried

```
<input type='textbox' name='qtybox' id='qtybox' style='width:20px;'> <a href=""/Cart.asp?Code=123456&QTY='+document.getElementById('qtybox').value;'"" onclick=""somefunction(this, event); return false;"" title=""Add To Cart""><img src=""testbutton.gif"" alt=""Add To Cart"" title=""Add To Cart""/></a>
```

But it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have so many double "" quotes? This looks like it's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from all the double `"` quotes, you are trying to build a string in javascript for the href which does not work that way.

The simplest solution would be to add the url-part to your somefunction function that you have specified as your onclick handler (that ends with return false anyway).

Or, you could try:

```
<input id="qtybox">

<a   href="#" 
    title="Add To Cart" 
  onclick="this.href='/Cart.asp?Code=123456&QTY='   
                      +document.getElementById('qtybox').value;
           somefunction(this, event); return true;">
 <img src="testbutton.gif" alt="Add To Cart" title="Add To Cart" />
</a>
```

See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/acMrj/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed like this and tried ??

problem with the expression.its taking `document.getElementById('qtybox').value` as string i think.

```
 <input type='textbox' name='qtybox' id='qtybox' style='width:20px;'> <a href="/Cart.asp?Code=123456&QTY="document.getElementById('qtybox').value;" onclick=""somefunction(this, event); return false;"" title=""Add To Cart""><img src=""testbutton.gif"" alt=""Add To Cart"" title=""Add To Cart""/></a>
```